# is this possible "select * , (additionalcolumn?) from anytable" in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

As you might know we use * char for select all columns. But,

if I want to add a new column to all columns near, for example;

```
SET    @examplevariable = 'hi guys';

select * , @examplevariable from anytable
```

otherwise Am I have to call all columns with their name?? something like;

```
select col1,col2, ... , @examplevariable from anytable
```

is the first option possible? or Are there any same easy way to do it??

Comment: Ya you'll want to alias it tho, @examplevariable as 'colName'

Comment: We use '*', but you shouldn't ;-)

Comment: when I said "We use", I mean all programmers.

Answer (score 1):

```
select at.*,
       42 as some_column
from anytable as at;
```

Comment: it comes me interesting. But it works. thanks. It saved me from the writing all columns names